# How to prevent gnome-sound applet from automatically reducing mic volume?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, sound, microphone

It happens all the time, when i'm talking to someone on Skype or Google Voice and Video, the mic volume automatically keeps going down, as if it is trying to auto-adjust it. I want to disable this feature, because it takes the volume down to inaudible levels.

Comment: If it is only on Skype ok, but also Google Voice it's a system issue, I have the same

Comment: I also have this issue, but not just in Skype, in everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Skype "feature", you can disable it in the sound devices tab in the Skype settings panel.

Comment: Awesome! This has been bugging me for a while. +1!

Comment: I guess it works fine on windows and is just broken on linux.

Comment: it isn't broken, it is "auto-ajusting", some people find it helpful, some don't

Comment: yup, agreed, that is the why of the "feature" pointer.